# Can I use custom header in nginx location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Is any body know if below block will work in nginx? Because current I don't have a front end that I cannot test if it works. If anybody knows, please let me know. thank you.

```
location /$http_x_customer_header {

    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_pass http://app/$http_x_customer_header ;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work - location directive recognizes only constant strings or regular expressions. So this will be taken literally, not as a variable. You can try with `location /` to catch any location.